# Multithreading in python pool.map raises TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying multithreading for the first time in Python. I see [documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html). Following is my sample code

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(4)
mylist = [3,4,5,6,7,8, ..., 5]
results = pool.map(my_method, my_list) # from docs it is clear that pool.map takes method and argument as a list 

def my_method(mylist):
    data = []
    for i in range (len(mylist)):
        # do something using mylist = subdata
        data.append(subdata)
    return data
```

It returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/algorithm.py", line 30, in my_method
    for i in range (len(mylist)):
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

From the documentation it is clear that `pool.map` takes function and a list ([see this tutorial too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-to-use-threading-in-python)) but why it is assuming `my_list` as a `float` giving this error. Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does this bit of code do?

```
results = pool.map(my_method, my_list)
```

It calls `my_method` multiple times, each times passing in a single element from your list `my_list` see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map

> map(func, iterable[, chunksize])
>   A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it
>   submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size
>   of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive
>   integer.

So

```
for i in range (len(mylist)):
```

is actually calling `len` on an `int` or `float` did you perhaps mean

```
for i in range (mylist):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mylist = [3,4,5,6,7,8, ..., 5]
results = pool.map(my_method, my_list)
```

so `pool.map` takes a function and a list all right, but calls `my_method` with one element of the list for each slot (to perform a "distributed" loop)

So in your function `mylist` is one element of the list, not the list itself (and looping on it makes no sense since the loop is implictly done by the `map` function)